# ConcurrentModificationException although @Lock(LockType.READ) annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, glassfish

I have Java EE application on Glassfish 3.1.2.2

and by read() I get in following code a ConcurrentModificationException:

```
private Set<MonitoredService> connectedServices = new HashSet<MonitoredService>();

@Override @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
public void addConnectedService(MonitoredService service) {
    if (!connectedServices.contains(service)) {
        connectedServices.add(service);
    }
}

@Override  @Lock(LockType.READ)
public Set<MonitoredService> getConnectedServices() {
    return  Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<MonitoredService>(connectedServices));
}
```

I have thought the Lock annotation cares for synchronized access on the set?

Comment: Could you show the stack trace of the ConcurrentModificationException? And what is the package of Lock?

Comment: thank you, I will change a HashMap to Collections.synchronizedSet(..). Without a Glassfish locking.

Comment: Your current way gives more throughput in case of a read-mostly access pattern. I'd work on it a bit more if I were you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just because the function is synchronized does not mean that the actual collection is synchronized.  There is no way for you to guarantee that something else has not modified `connectedServices` even if it is within a singleton.  If you truly need a synchronized collection use:

```
Collections.synchronizedSet(...);
```

Comment: It's a private collection, so the guarantee is there.

Comment: hm ok, I have thought Glassfish makes a wonder and it works  without a synchronizedSet:)
Thank you!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik not really, you can use reflection and private disappears.  Granted this is being pedantic about reflection :)

Comment: Well, if you bring in reflection, then `synchronizedSet` isn't safe, either. It's trivial to access the underlying set and mutate ad libitum.